# TFS 2012 security - allow users to edit status of work items

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-security

My organization wants to use TFS to track user sign-off of work items by changing the work item Status.  The first user I asked to view a work item in TFS is being prevented from viewing the work item.  How do I set permissions for him to view and edit the work item status?

[image: screenshot of access denied error]

Comment: Are the users members of the "Valid Users" group?

Comment: They also technically need a Client Access License I believe.

Comment: they're valid users, @daveshaw.  Any more info on the client access license @aclear16?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access your `Web Portal` of project, select `Security section` ensure that your user have permission, exist in `Contributors Group` that contains permission. (Best practise is to set contributor group to your members team)